# Why dictionary keys and values can be unpacked as a tuple when they are a string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tuples

I've this code:

```
my_dict = {"one":"AAA", "two":"BBB", "thr":"CCC"}
for a, b, c in my_dict.keys():
    print(a, b, c)
print("-----")   
for x, y, z in my_dict.values():
    print(x, y, z)
```

and it returns below output when run.

```
o n e
t w o
t h r
-----
A A A
B B B
C C C
```

Can someone explain why is it able to unpack keys and values as a tuple when they are of string type?

I know `my_dict.items()` can be unpacked as a tuple of type (a, b) because `my_dict.items()` returns a tuple. But why here when the return type is string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the dictionaries themselves.

This solely works because strings are "unpackable" since they are iterable.

Your code works due to the same reason the below works:

```
a, b, c = 'abc'
print(a, b, c)
# a b c
```

Note that your examples (and the code in my example) will break if any of the strings happen to be shorter or longer  than 3 characters:

```
a, b, c = 'abcd'
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

a, b, c = 'ab'
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: Yes, observed that it breaks when the strings are of different length. And you're right that it's related to strings actually.